# Where to put utility functions in a React-Redux application?

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs, redux, utility-method

In a React-Redux application, I've got a state like this:

```
state = {
    items: [
        { id: 1, first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", country: "us" },
        { id: 2, first_name: "Jinping", last_name: "Xi", country: "cn" },
    ]
}
```

which I render using a React component.

Now I need a function that gives me the "full name" of a person. So it's not just "first_name + last_name" but it depends on the country (for example, it would be "last_name + first_name" in China), so there's some relatively complex logic, which I would like to wrap in a function usable from any React component.

In OOP I would create a `Person::getFullName()` method that would give me this information. However the `state` object is a "dumb" one where sub-objects don't have any specialized methods.

So what is the recommended way to manage this in React-Redux in general? All I can think of is create a global function such as `user_getFullName(user)` which would take a user and return the full name, but that's not very elegant. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I follow the approach of creating libraries for cases like this in my applications, and so far this works pretty well for me.

In this case, I would **create a new module**, e.g. `{ComponentRoot}/lib/user.js` which exports a function `getFullName(user)` or possibly `getFullName(firstName, lastName, country)`, depending the circumstances.

Now it is just a matter of **importing the module where you require the functionality**, no global functions needed:

```
import React from 'react'
import {getFullName} from '../lib/user'

const Title = ({user}) =>
    <div>
        {getFullName(user)}
    </div>
```

---

We place our library folder on the same level as the components folder etc., but whatever works best for you should do.

Answer (score 32):

First of all, [Redux has no opinion on the file structure of your application](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1709).
Some famous boilerplate projects put the code into a `utils/` folder:

- [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/tree/master/app/utils)
- [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/tree/master/src/utils)
- [react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/tree/master/src/utils)
- [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/tree/master/app/utils)

**Sample folder structure:**

```
src/
  components/
    ...
  reducers/
    ...
  utils/
    ...
```